# Finding contradicting example for limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm solving some extra questions in calculus, and I'm having trouble finding contradicting examples (there are only final solutions).

I do understand intuitively why the statements are false, but it's difficult to think of contradicting example.

I'd be very grateful if anyone can give me a lead on those to find contradicting example for:

1. $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=\infty \land \lim_{x\to \infty}   
       f(g(x))=\infty \implies \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=\infty$
2. $\lim_{x\to 5} f(x)=5  \implies \lim_{x\to 5} f(f(x))=5$

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one assume

- $f(x)=\tan x$
- $g(x)= \frac \pi 2+2\pi\lfloor x\rfloor -\frac1x \to \infty$

then $f(g(x)) \to \infty$ but $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ doesn't exist.

For the second one consider

- $f(x)=0$ for $x\in \mathbb N$
- $f(x)=\lfloor x+\frac12\rfloor $ otherwise

then $\lim_{x\to 5} f(x)=5$ but $\lim_{x\to 5} f(f(x))=0$.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: $g(x)$ is defined in such way to approach from the left $\frac \pi 2+2\pi n$ therefore $\tan (g(x)) \to \infty$.

Comment: yes, I just got it. thank you once again!

Comment: @E.Ginzburg You are welcome! Bye